# SymtabAPI doesn't implicity change binary

Tags: symbol-tables

I'm using the DyninstAPI (namely, the SymtabAPI component) to rewrite the symbol tables in binaries.  I'm using the following methods to do so:

```
data_region->setPtrToRawData((void*) new_raw, data_region->getRegionSize())
```

The method returns successfully, I check my error codes, and I even re-read the data section which has successfully been replaced.  The problem is that the original binary isn't rewritten with the new raw `.data` section, and the original raw `.data` section persists.

I've scoured the manual to see if there is some sort of *commit* function but none is documented and nothing of the sort is mentioned in the examples.  **EDIT**: I just read through some of the source code for the `Region` class, and it looks like I'm essentially doing what `patchData` does (in case that is the method I should be using).

Suggestions?

The programming manuals are available at http://www.paradyn.org/html/manuals.html.

*P.S. hopefully a more reputable user can add the tags `DyninstAPI` and `SymtabAPI` for me.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting with the developers, they alerted me that the function I needed to call was `emit` and the syntax I ended up using was:

```
symtab_obj->emit("new_binary.out");
```

Thanks Drew!